# Mathematical induction proving formula with only k-2

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, proof-writing

The sequence is defined by s<sub>k</sub> = 2s<sub>k-2</sub>, and the first 2 terms are 1 and 2.  So the sequence looks like 1,2,2,4,4,8,8,16,16...

I'm supposed to write an explicit formula for the sequence.  I went with S(n) = 2<sup>1/4(2n+1-(-1)<sup>n</sup>)</sup>.  Is this right?  It seems impossible to prove with induction since s<sub>k-1</sub> is unrelated to s<sub>k</sub>.  Am I supposed to write two formulas, one for even and one for odd?

Comment: This question is not well phrased. There needs to be a starting number, to get the sequence going, so to speak.

Comment: Prove it separately for even and odd n.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one predicate that you can perform normal induction on to get the result:

> Let $P(k) = ( S(k)=\cdots \land S(k+1)=\cdots )$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> where you fill in the formula you want to prove in "$\cdots$".

You will find that you can now prove that ( $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$ ) for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and the rest is easy.